# Where to edit sublime text js beautify setting?

Tags: sublime-text-plugin, js-beautify

I am trying to use sublime text Javascript Beautify [plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javascript%20Beautify), and it says I need to change to below setting:

```
{
  "indent_size": 4,
  "indent_char": " ",
  "indent_level": 0,
  "indent_with_tabs": false,
  "preserve_newlines": true,
  "max_preserve_newlines": 10,
  "jslint_happy": false,
  "brace_style": "collapse",
  "keep_array_indentation": false,
  "keep_function_indentation": false,
  "space_before_conditional": true,
  "break_chained_methods": false,
  "eval_code": false,
  "unescape_strings": false,
  "wrap_line_length": 0,

  // jsbeautify options
  "format_on_save": true
}
```

Where exactly do I have to make this change in sublime text?

Comment: Probably @ Menu/Preferences/PackageSettings/JavaScriptBeautify/Settings-User

Comment: Thank you! appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All package settings can be accessed from the `Preferences/Package Settings` menu.

[image]

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/259968)